# Restlet find origin IP

Tags: java, restlet

I would like to find out the origin IP address a request came from to my resource.
I have the next two methods to retrieve it.

```
String ipAddress = (Series) Request.getCurrent().getAttributes().
                    get("org.restlet.http.headers").getFirstValue("X-Forwarded-For");
String ip = ipAddress.split(" ")[0];
```

and

```
List<String> ipsList = Request.getCurrent().getClientInfo().getForwardedAddresses();
String ip = ipsList.get(ipsList.size() - 1);
```

**Two questions:**

1. Are they both **correct** (does it work)?
2. Which is **better** (if they both work, which is better regarding efficiency/resources/runtime)?

Comment: You need to tell us what you mean by "correct" and "better."

Comment: correct - does it work. Better - if they both work, which is better regarding efficiency/resources/runtime

Comment: I think that it's better to use the Restlet API instead of the value of headers. Restlet extracts such hints from headers and gives you access to it via API. So in your case, I would prefer the second approach ;-) Hope it helps you!

Comment: I tend to the second one as well. Yet I'm not 100% sure it works

Comment: I had a look at the Restlet source code and it's filled using the content of the header `X-Forwarded-For` ;-) See class `org.restlet.data.ClientInfo` in module `org.restlet`...

Comment: I know (reading the documentation) that it suppose to work. I ask if anyone actually tried to use it...

Comment: I'll make a try ;-) For information, you can just add the header manually within a tool like Postman and check on the server side if you get the value...

Comment: I actually use postman and did added the header manually for check. But it is a local check, not absolutely sure it work not in lab conditions. Therefore I ask for others experience on the subject.

Comment: Using **Postman** I try to issue a request with the header _X-Forwarded-For_ (with 0.0.0.0) but in my resource, `request.getClientInfo().getForwardedAddresses()` gives me an empty list... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This feature isn't enabled by default. See javadocs of the class `ClientInfo`. If you use Restlet in a standalone mode, you can do this: `server.getContext().getParameters().add("useForwardedForHeader", "true");` (see http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/base/connectors). Hope it helps